# What different styles of camera bags exist, and how are they different?

Tags: camera-bag, equipment-protection

As a beginner just starting out in photography, I find myself on the lookout for a good camera bag that will make it easier to keep my camera with me as much as possible. However, without the  experience to know what to look for or how to evaluate what I find, it is easy to get lost in the torrent of available options.

**What are the different styles of camera bags in common use, and what are the pros and cons of each?**

Comment: I think this could all come under the one question, don't you think? http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-i-choose-a-camera-bag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems I already wrote the perfect article for you ;) Here it is: [Camera Bag Guide](http://www.neocamera.com/article.php?id=camera_bags)

The importance is to understand the trade-off between each type of bag in terms of:

- Carrying size - How much equipment? How heavy?
- Accessibility - How fast can you get your gear out of it?
- Comfort - How the weight is distributed? How does it interfere with your movements?
- Airline compliance - Carry-on size? Personal item size?

Different bag types offer various trade-offs among these.

Answer (score 1):

#### Smallest Suitable Bag

One factor I have found is that if my bag is too big then I leave it at home rather than grab it and bring it with me.

The solution for me has been to find the smallest possible bag which holds all the gear I always want.  Personally, I have the [Lowepro Slingshot 100](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lowepro-Slingshot-Digital-Lenses-Panasonic/dp/B000BAX50G/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1305024346&sr=1-3), which seems to have been replaced by the [Slingshot 102](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lowepro-SlingShot-102AW-Photo-Sling/dp/B003656Q7C/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1305024346&sr=1-2).

I also own bigger bags which I use when I'm going on a shoot or a trip, and I want to take everything with me, but from your question, I think you're after an everyday always-with-you bag.

Hope that helps.